# How can i pass parametersfrom a windows batch script to java

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to read some parameters , which are defined in a windows batch script,in my java program...
How can i define parameters..?
for eg
I need to read a variable which is defined in the script;
variable v=XYX

i tried defining like(in the script);

```
java  -Dvariable=XYX
```

but getting following exception;

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the main method of your class first

> java com.xyz.MyClass -Dvariable=XYX